# Data Partition for In sample and out of sample forecasting in neural network

Tags: neural-networks, out-of-sample, in-sample

I got confused with how to do data partition that reflects in sample and out of sample forecast when I do time series forecasting in neural network.

What I understand is we have to divide data into:
- training data set --> to estimate the model
- validation data set --> to generalize and avoid overfitting
- test data set --> to see model's performance

Does it mean that:
- in sample forecasting: training and validation? if so, which performance should I see as in sample performance, the training MSE or the validation MSE?
- out of sample forecasting = test data set?